# Oldish-way async call doesn't go into its callback method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, callback, delegates

I try to figure out ancestor of the async-await usage in .Net using `WebRequest`. In the following code, I expect to get into `GetWebResponseCallback` passed through `BeginGetResponse` but it is not. What's the missing point?

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;    
using Newtonsoft.Json;
class X
{
 public static void GetWebResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("test");
            WebRequest request = (WebRequest)result.AsyncState;
            WebResponse response = request.EndGetResponse(result);
            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response));
        }
        // read the data, and process it...

        public static void GetWebResponse(string url)
        {
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
            /*WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            // read the data and process it...
            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response));
       */
            request.BeginGetResponse(GetWebResponseCallback, request);

        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var url = "https://github.com/timbrel/GitSavvy/actions/workflows/lint.yml/badge.svg"; ;
            GetWebResponse(url);
            Console.WriteLine("hax");

        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your application not waiting for finish response and closes right after you call `GetWebResponse` and `Console.WriteLine`. This is why `GetWebResponseCallback` simply does not have time to execute before the program is terminated.

You can add some waiting to your main method to prevent terminating the program:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var url = "https://github.com/timbrel/GitSavvy/actions/workflows/lint.yml/badge.svg"; ;
    GetWebResponse(url);
    Console.WriteLine("hax");

    // wait for user input
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

It's not a production ready solution but it is enough to demonstrate that callback function was executed after the request was finished. In a more complex scenario, you can wait the completion signal explicitly using synchronisation mechanisms such as [`ManualResetEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.manualresetevent).

> ManualResetEvent class represents a thread synchronization event that, when signaled, must be reset manually. This class cannot be inherited.

You can create an `ManualResetEvent` instance, pass it as state to the callback and call it inside callback function:

```
class X
{
    public static void GetWebResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("test");
        var state = (RequestState)result.AsyncState;
        WebResponse response = state.Request.EndGetResponse(result);
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response));

        // send signal that async operation is complete
        state.CompleteEvent.Set();
    }

    public static void GetWebResponse(string url, ManualResetEvent manualResetEvent)
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
        var state = new RequestState { Request = request, CompleteEvent = manualResetEvent };
        request.BeginGetResponse(GetWebResponseCallback, state);
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var url = "https://github.com/timbrel/GitSavvy/actions/workflows/lint.yml/badge.svg";
        var manualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        GetWebResponse(url, manualResetEvent);
        Console.WriteLine("soner");
        
        // Wait for async operation to complete
        manualResetEvent.WaitOne();
    }

    public class RequestState
    {
        public WebRequest Request { get; set; }
        public ManualResetEvent CompleteEvent { get; set; }
    }
}
```